# DnD random encounter generator

Tags: python

My Dm asked for a random encounter generator.
Using python, currently I have it calculate the mean of the party level plus a linear difficulty scaler(bob) set to the challenge rating for a sample of enemies.
What I am having trouble with is getting a sample of random enemies whose cr is equal to bob. I've been trying variations of:

```
var = [int(a.cr), int(b.cr), int(c.cr), int(d.cr)]

if bob <= 4:
    print(random.choices(var))
```

I don't know how to set it equal to bob much less have multiple enemies equal bob.

I know this is a noob question and it drives me crazy that I'm struggling with this but any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit unclear what you are asking; maybe you are looking for something like this?

```
enemies = [a, b, c, d]
enemies_with_target_cr = [enemy for enemy in enemies if int(enemy.cr) == bob]
selected_enemies = random.choices(enemies_with_target_cr)
```